# change scene upon reaching specific score

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm very new to unity and coding so I have some doubt here. I'm current creating a multiple choice quiz game. can someone help w the coding for my question. My question here is I need to change scene upon reaching certain point. for example, when my score hits 30 I want winner page to appear and when my score hits 0 I want you lose page to appear. how?

Comment: you should show your minimum code

Comment: Hi Shamini Balu, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. 
It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer because you didn't show us the exact code where you count scores. But I will try to help you as much as I can.

Enter your code where you count scores (where you have that variable that stores scores). Now, above the code, among other "using" statements add

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
```

So you just added a scene manager into your script to have control over scenes. Now inside your Update() function add

```
if (score<0)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("LoserPage"); //player lost
}


if (score>29)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("WinnerPage"); //player won
}
```

In the code above *score* is a variable that stores your scores. Change that to whatever you have that does it. LoserPage and WinnderPage are the names of the scenes that you have created. Change their names to whatever you have to make it work. Don't forget to add your scenes in Build settings in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class AnswerButtons : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject answerAbackBlue; // blue is waiting
    public GameObject answerAbackGreen; // green is correct 
    public GameObject answerAbackRed; // red is wrong answer

    public GameObject answerBbackBlue; // blue is waiting
    public GameObject answerBbackGreen; // green is correct 
    public GameObject answerBbackRed; // red is wrong answer

    public GameObject answerCbackBlue; // blue is waiting
    public GameObject answerCbackGreen; // green is correct 
    public GameObject answerCbackRed; // red is wrong answer

    public GameObject answerDbackBlue; // blue is waiting
    public GameObject answerDbackGreen; // green is correct 
    public GameObject answerDbackRed; // red is wrong answer

    public GameObject answerA;
    public GameObject answerB;
    public GameObject answerC;
    public GameObject answerD;

    public AudioSource CorrectFX;
    public AudioSource WrongFX;

    public GameObject currentScore;
    public int scoreValue;

    void Update() {
        currentScore.GetComponent<Text>().text = "SCORE:  " + scoreValue;

        if (scoreValue > 300)
            SceneManager.LoadScene("WinnerPage");

        if (scoreValue < 50)
            SceneManager.LoadScene("LoserPage");

    }

    public void AnswerA() {
        if (QuestionGenarate.actualAnswer == "A") {
            answerAbackGreen.SetActive(true);
            answerAbackBlue.SetActive(false);
            CorrectFX.Play();
            scoreValue += 10;
        } else {
            answerAbackRed.SetActive(true);
            answerAbackBlue.SetActive(false);
            WrongFX.Play();
            scoreValue -= 5;
        }

        answerA.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
        answerB.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
        answerC.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
        answerD.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
        StartCoroutine(NextQuestion());
    }

    public void AnswerB() {
        if (QuestionGenarate.actualAnswer == "B") {
            answerBbackGreen.SetActive(true);
            answerBbackBlue.SetActive(false);
            CorrectFX.Play();
            scoreValue += 10;
        } else {
            answerBbackRed.SetActive(true);
            answerBbackBlue.SetActive(false);
            WrongFX.Play();
            scoreValue -= 5;
        }

        answerA.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
        answerB.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
        answerC.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
        answerD.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
        StartCoroutine(NextQuestion());
    }

    public void AnswerC() {
        if (QuestionGenarate.actualAnswer == "C") {
            answerCbackGreen.SetActive(true);
            answerCbackBlue.SetActive(false);
            CorrectFX.Play();
            scoreValue += 10;
        } else {
            answerCbackRed.SetActive(true);
            answerCbackBlue.SetActive(false);
            WrongFX.Play();
            scoreValue -= 5;
        }

        answerA.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
        answerB.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
        answerC.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
        answerD.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
        StartCoroutine(NextQuestion());
    }

    public void AnswerD() {
        if (QuestionGenarate.actualAnswer == "D") {
            answerDbackGreen.SetActive(true);
            answerDbackBlue.SetActive(false);
            CorrectFX.Play();
            scoreValue += 10;
        } else {
            answerDbackRed.SetActive(true);
            answerDbackBlue.SetActive(false);
            WrongFX.Play();
            scoreValue -= 5;
        }

        answerA.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
        answerB.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
        answerC.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
        answerD.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
        StartCoroutine(NextQuestion());
    }

    IEnumerator NextQuestion() {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

        answerAbackGreen.SetActive(false);
        answerBbackGreen.SetActive(false);
        answerCbackGreen.SetActive(false);
        answerDbackGreen.SetActive(false);
        answerAbackRed.SetActive(false);
        answerBbackRed.SetActive(false);
        answerCbackRed.SetActive(false);
        answerDbackRed.SetActive(false);
        answerAbackBlue.SetActive(false);
        answerBbackBlue.SetActive(false);
        answerCbackBlue.SetActive(false);
        answerDbackBlue.SetActive(false);
        answerA.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = true;
        answerB.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = true;
        answerC.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = true;
        answerD.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = true;
        QuestionGenarate.displayingQuestion = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your LoserPage will appear immediately after starting the game. Because scoreValue is zero at the start. Make LoserPage appear when scoreValue<0

Comment: I tried it and this works out. Thank you so muchh